# Android to Kotlin best practice to convert

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two classes, one of which extends the other

First class:

```
open class DataBaseObject @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ctx: Context,
    val iD: Int,
    val name: String,
    displayName: String = ""
) {
    var displayName: String? = null

    init {
        if (displayName === "") {
            val wasteStringKey = ctx.resources.getIdentifier(name, "string", ctx.packageName)
            if (wasteStringKey != 0) this.displayName =
                ctx.getString(wasteStringKey) else this.displayName =
                name.replace("_", " ")
        } else this.displayName = displayName
    }

    open fun getDisplayName(): String? {
        return displayName
    }

    open fun getID(): Int {
        return iD
    }

    open fun getName(): String? {
        return name
    }
}
```

The second(android version):

```
public class Language extends DataBaseObject
{
    private String _abbreviation;
    
    public Language(Context ctx, int id, String abbreviation, String name)
    {
        super(ctx, id, name);
        
        _abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
    
    public String getAbbreviation()
    {
        return _abbreviation;
    }
}
```

But if I copy paste the code into my class, the IDE converts me to kotlin like this:

(Kotlin version)

```
open class Language(ctx: Context?, id: Int, val abbreviation: String, name: String?) :
    DataBaseObject(ctx!!, id, name!!)
```

In another class I use the function
`getAbbreviation() -> val locale = Locale(dbc.getLangaugeByID(SELECTED_LANGUAGE_ID).getAbbrevation())` and I get the Unresolved Reference error.
What is the best way to convert java class to kotlin?

I expect to be able to use that method, or an equivalent alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use

```
val locale = Locale(dbc.getLangaugeByID(SELECTED_LANGUAGE_ID).abbreviation)
```

In kotlin it's not idiomatic to use getter methods and you typically just access the properties directly. In fact if you left it as a `Java` class you could call `getAbbreviation()` by simply writing `abbreviation` from `Kotlin` and it works automatically, and the IDE most likely even suggests you to write that instead of using the getter. This is called property access syntax. The same as when you can write `getApplication()` inside an `Activity` it will recommend you to just use `application`. See

[image]

In that respect is the generated class identical to the `Java` class. Note that you don't need to worry that maybe the `abbreviation` can be set that way also, because that's not possible since it's a `val`. It's just like having only a getter